# windmill dataset in the Netherlands

Tags: data-request, geospatial, europe

Since the Netherlands is famous with the windmill, how come I can't find the spatial dataset of it? I tried to look at :

```
https://www.pdok.nl/
https://data.overheid.nl/
https://data.amsterdam.nl/
https://utrecht.dataplatform.nl/
http://rotterdamopendata.nl/
https://denhaag.dataplatform.nl/
```

Anyone knows where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org) data? You can use the [man_made=windmill tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:man_made%3Dwindmill)

> A traditional windmill, historically used to mill grain with wind power.

[image]

This Overpass Turbo link will give you all windmills in the Netherlands. Note that this will include a fair amount of insignificant tiny windmills used to hose water from a canal in a polder, not the typical "picture post-card" type big ones that you can enter and may even have living quarters. Most of these can be detected by a "name" or "description" tag of "Poldermolen", but there is no guarantee this is accurate.

[Overpass Turbo query link for windmills in the Netherlands](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/SET)

---

screenshot of sample results:

[image: screenshot of sample results]